# Eclipse crashes with reference count error message cairo_surface_destroy

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, papyrus

My Eclipse with papyrus (2018-12) crashes on Linux (16.04) with the following error:

```
cairo-surface.c:953:cairo_surface_destroy:Assertion`CAIRO_REFERENCE_COUNT_HAS_REFERENCE `(_cairo_atomic_int_get (&(&surface->ref_count)->ref_count) > 0)' failed.
```

I am using eclipse-papyrus to create uml for spring state machine. It is very annoying when the eclipse crashes. The bug is usually happen when I try to zoom in or zoom out the diagram. I have found that similar bug is reported:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544501

I have tried to work around the problem adding the following vm arguments to eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=false
```

It is not working for me. I wonder if it is some another way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

While I've considered this issue for a long time as an SWT/GTK problem, it seems to be rather a GMF runtime issue, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552568